# npm error:A valid query string passed to parseQuery should begin with '?'

Tags: webpack, vue.js

Once I run `npm run build`in my vue2 project,an error explained that`loaderUtils.getOptions is not a function`.

After I `cnpm install vue-loader vue-template-compiler loader-utils` ,the following error occurred：

```
    ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
      Module build failed: Error: A valid query string passed to parseQuery should b  egin with '?'

      - parseQuery.js:13 Object.parseQuery
        [cg.test]/[_loader-utils@1.1.0@loader-utils]/lib/parseQuery.js:13:9


      - Error: A valid query string passed to parseQuery should begin with '?'

      - compiler.js:76
        [cg.test]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16

      - Compiler.js:296 Compiler.<anonymous>
        [cg.test]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:296:10

      - Compiler.js:499
        [cg.test]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:499:13

      - Tapable.js:202 next
        [cg.test]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:202:11

      - CachePlugin.js:62 Compiler.<anonymous>
        [cg.test]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:62:5

      …… ……    

> ERROR in ./src/main.js
>     Module build failed: Error: A valid query string passed to parseQuery should begin with '?'
>         at Object.parseQuery (D:\***\node_modules\_loader-utils@1.1.0@loader-utils\lib\parseQuery.js:13:9)
>         at Object.module.exports (D:***\node_modules\_babel-loader@6.4.1@babel-loader\lib\index.js:104:35)
>     
>  Build complete.
>     
>   Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
>   Opening index.html over file:// won't work.
```

I used to update the version of the `babel-loader`，`vue-cli`,`vue-loader`, `vue-template-compiler`,`loader-utils`,`webpack`or`npm install`,but none of them work.Does anybody know the problem?

Comment: This might help you out: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/727

Comment: Thank you so much. It gives me a big hand.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment's help.

I used to solve the problem by the following issue of html-webpack-plugin,

[1]https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/727

[2]https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/pull/663

(find out the problem of the version of `html-webpack-plugin` on your `package-lock.json` )

It exactly solved this error,but the other occurred:`chunk.sortModules is not a function`,`loaderUtils.parseQuery`,`Cannot resolve module 'vux/undefined' is not a function` and so on.

So finally I cancelled the `node_module` and **package-lock.json**,and then I `npm install` again.

It works~